# iOS app rejected for using E-Mail verification (4.2.3)

Tags: ios, swift, appstore-approval

So our app got rejected for using E-Mail based account verification. We just send a link that takes the user directly back to the app and thats it. Now apple says that we must not be using the Mail app in order to validate the user.

Apple sent the following rejection message (Guideline 4.2.3 - Design):

*We noticed that we were required to install the Mail app before we* 
*could use your app. Apps should be able to run on launch, without* 
*requiring additional apps to be installed.*

*Next Steps*

*To resolve this issue, please revise your app to ensure that users* 
*can use it upon launch. If your app requires authentication before* 
*use, please use methods that can authenticate users from within your* 
*app.*

Asking for how to proceed, they sent the following response (4. 2 Design: Minimum Functionality):

*For a good user experience, the registration process should take place* *inside the app, and should not require user to use other apps, like* *Mail.*

Now first of all thanks alot apple, this is not random at all! Just the way 90% of all apps do it!

We have a button that takes the user directly to the Mail app, and are unsure whether that might be triggering some automated test rejection.

```
if let mailURL = URL(string: "message://"), 
UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(mailURL) {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(mailURL)
}
```

Does anyone have an idea howto resolve this issue, without actually removing the Email verification (or probably any user verification at all)?

Comment: You were not rejected for using Email verification. You were rejected for relying on opening an app that may not exist on the user's device. Just remove the button and tell the user to check their email. Do not complain about Apple when your app does not do what it is supposed to do. You can test this yourself very easily, but you didn't. Get a phone with the app on, now uninstall all of the optional apps and run your app.

Comment: So attempting to help the user and saving him a click on the home button gets you rejected, very good thinking. Instead, let him open Safari and log in to webmail. Great!

Comment: Not at all. But if you provide a button to open the Mail app and they don't have the mail app then you're not helping anyone. Think about it before complaining about it.

Comment: Apple allows the setting of a default mail client: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201607

I have not seen any update in the developer documentation about whether this changes the wisdom of assuming someone has an email app installed.

Answer (score 0):

Fogmeister is absolutely correct. You expect the user to use another app, which can be not installed on his/her phone. While your app should work on its own without requiring installation of another app to function.